# Android PaintView - OutOfMemoryException

Tags: android, out-of-memory

When I inflate the `PaintView`, it shows `OutOfMemoryException` sometimes. I used bitmap for that to scratch the image and based on that I resize that image.

Here is My Code :

```
public class PaintView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
Bitmap Bitmap1, Bitmap2;
Bitmap Transparent;
Bitmap overlay;
int X = -100;
int Y = -100;
Canvas c2;
private boolean isTouched = false;

// List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
Paint paint = new Paint();

public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    initView(context);
}

public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initView(context);
}

 @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
private void initView(Context context) {
     setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;

        Transparent = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);


        /*Bitmap2 = BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.main);
       */ 

        Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.scratch_image);

       /* int width1 = bitmapOrg.getWidth();

        int height1 = bitmapOrg.getHeight();


        int newWidth = width;

        int newHeight  = height;

        // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f

         float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width1;

         float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height1;

         Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

         matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
         //matrix.postRotate(90);
         // this will create image with new size
         Bitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg,bitmapOrg.getWidth(),bitmapOrg.getHeight(),width, height, matrix, true);


    */    
        Bitmap2=bitmapOrg.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOrg, width, height, true);

        c2 = new Canvas();

        c2.setBitmap(Transparent);
          //        c2.drawBitmap(Bitmap1, 0, 0, null);
        c2.drawBitmap(Bitmap2, 0, 0, paint);
        paint.setAlpha(0);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_OUT));
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);   
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    System.out.println("onDraw");
    c2.drawCircle(X, Y, 50, paint);
    if(isTouched)
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap1, 0, 0, null);
    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(Transparent, 0, 0, null);

}

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    isTouched = true;
    X = (int) event.getX();
    Y = (int) event.getY();

    invalidate();
    return true;
}
 }

  class Point {
float x, y;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return x + ", " + y;
}
 }
```

here is my xml:

```
 <com.test.test.lottery.PaintView   
      android:id="@+id/img1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Comment: can you share your image resolution and size?

Comment: Call `bitmapOrg.recycle()` right after `Bitmap2` is created, or downsample like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/823966/718379

Comment: @StackOverflowUser image : 640*1136 and 111kb

Comment: can you post your full error log?